# How to get data from one table and use it in another in sequelize(postgres)

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I have 2 models for database, user and his post

modelUser.js

```
const User = sequelize.define('user', {
    id: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true},
    email: {type: DataTypes.STRING, unique: true},
    password: {type: DataTypes.STRING},
});
```

modelPost.js

```
const Post = sequelize.define('post', {
    author: {type: DataTypes.STRING},
    title: {type: DataTypes.STRING},
    content: {type: DataTypes.STRING}
});
```

I create a createPost method, and in order to create a new element in the 'post' table, I need to get the user's email from the 'user' table, and then assign the email value to the 'author' field

```
async createPost(req,res) {
        try {
            const {author} = await User.findOne({where: {email}}); //this does not work
            console.log(author);
            const {title, content} = req.body;
            /*if(!title || !content) {
                return res.status(400).json({message: 'Title or content cannot be empty'});
            }
            const post = await Post.create({author, title, content})*/
            return res.json({post});
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e.message);
        }
    }
```

So, how do I access the user table and get the email of a specific user? To check if the user is registered use authMiddleware

```
router.post('/registration', userController.registration);
router.post('/login', userController.login);
router.get('/get', authMiddleware, userController.findAll);
router.post('/getOne',authMiddleware, userController.findOne);
router.post('/post', authMiddleware, userController.createPost);
```

Comment: What's the problem? Don't have access to tables? And I recommend reading about foreign keys and database denormalization

Comment: The problem is that how can I get the data of a specific registered user (there is a token). That is, the user is authorized, he has an email. And now I need to get this email stored in another table in the {author} field

Comment: I have User.hasMany(Post);
Post.belongsTo(User);

Answer (score 0):

Hello [@andreySmith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19270098/andrey-smith),
the destructuring you're doing is not correct (check the below lines).

```
const {author} = await User.findOne({where: {email}}); //You need to update this line as below in createPost().

const {email} = await User.findOne({where: {email}});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you written before the trouble lies at this line

> const {author} = await User.findOne({where: {email}});

And the solution is pretty simple.
When you're trying to destructure you either have to use the same name as the object has i.e. in this case it's `email`

```js
 const { email } = await User.findOne({where: {email}});
```

or  use naming destructuring so your line should be transformed into something like this:

```js
 const { email : author } = await User.findOne({where: {email}});
```

Now you can use `author` variable that contains value from `email`.